# Auditing Exchange 2007 Mailbox Full Access Permissions with Powershell

Tags: powershell, permissions, audit, exchange-server-2007

I on occasion I get asked to produce a list of users who have Full Access rights to a particular Exchange 2007 Mailbox. At the moment I am doing this manually, and I'd ideally like to do it with Powershell.

Is there anyway to produce a list of Full Access Permissions (and Send On Behalf rights would also be useful).

Thanks,
Jonny

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Send-As permissions are stored in active directory, so it's a bit tricky to get at them.  You could use Add-Member if you like to combine the properties you care about from the two results.

Full Access:

```
get-mailbox | %{$foo = $_; Get-MailboxPermission $foo | ?{$_.AccessRights -eq "FullAccess" -and $_.IsInherited -eq $false}} | ft {$foo},User,AccessRights
```

Send-As:

```
get-mailbox | %{$mailbox = $_; Get-ADPermission $mailbox.DistinguishedName | ?{$_.ExtendedRights -like "Send-As" -and $_.User -notlike "NT AUTHORITY\SELF"}} | ft {$mailbox},user,{"Send-As"}
```

Comment: Hi Slipsec! The Full Access one worked like a charm! Thanks! I have also answered below with a alternative to Send-As one that I worked out when trying this yesterday.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Slipsecs answer there is an alternative to the Send-As permissions audit.

```
$(Get-Mailbox -Identity mailboxName).GrantSendOnBehalfTo | ft Name
```

This returns only manually added users and no auto generated ones.

Thanks again Slipsec with your help on this!

Comment: I don't think that's an "alternative" but rather something else (even though many admins tend to set up both because they don't understand the difference). AFAIK, `GrantSentOnBehalfTo` corresponds to the "Send on behalf of" right (a.k.a. "Delegate") rather than the "Send As" permission? The main behavioural difference between the two is that with "Send on behalf" the recipient would still see the address of the actual sender in addition to the address you're sending on behalf of. With "Send As" there is no trace of any third party having been involved in the sending of the message.

Answer (score 1):

```
get-mailbox -identity MailBoxName | %{$foo = $_; Get-MailboxPermission $foo | ?{$_.AccessRights -eq "FullAccess" -and $_.IsInherited -eq $false}} | ft {$foo},User,AccessRights
```

If you're looking for permissions for users on a specific mailbox. Replace the MailBoxName with the exact name of the mailbox you're attempting to run the report on. It is KeySensitive with regards to the name of the mailbox and alias.

Answer (score 0):

`get-mailbox | %{$foo = $_; Get-MailboxPermission $foo | ?{$_.AccessRights -eq "FullAccess" -and $_.IsInherited -eq $false}} | ft {$foo},User,AccessRights`

in the above command, do i replace foo with the mailbox or the username ? I tried the command and it says cannot bind as object is null - will be grateful for your assistance.

Comment: Nope, $foo doesn't need to be changed. $foo is being set to each mailbox object because Get-Mailbox is being piped. So each mailbox is held in $_ which is then being assigned to $foo and can be accessed outside of the intial piping.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but just in case anyone else comes across this thread looking for help, to answer the OPs last question, `$foo` represents a variable that you have to define before running the command, so as n example:

```
$foo = 'Example User'

get-mailbox | %{$foo = $_; Get-MailboxPermission $foo | ?{$_.AccessRights -eq "FullAccess" -and $_.IsInherited -eq $false}} | ft {$foo},User,AccessRights
```

Comment: oops, didn't fully read the command, $foo is being defined already by get-mailbox